# Recursive functional

Tags: functions, recursion

Out of curiosity, we're looking for a function $φ$ such that $(φ ∘ φ)(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$.

For $x^2$, a trivial function is $φ(x) = x^{√2}$. Indeed: $(x^{√2})^{√2} = x^{√2 × √2} = x^2$.
Is there a general expression for any polynomial of degree 2?

Do you know where to find documentation about recursive functionals? I haven't found anything on Wikipedia.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Imo, to clarify your post and make it focus on a single question, you would just have to suppress the last paragraph (about "recursive functionals").